# How to solve an equation for a function (on LHS) and its derivative on the RHS?

Tags: integration, derivatives

E.g. the equation is

$u(x) = f(x) u'(x)$

Is there a general form of solving such an equation?

If not, is there a general form for $f(x)$ being a linear function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tips:

$$\dfrac{u'(x)}{u(x)}=\dfrac{1}{f(x)} \\ \ln [u(x)]=\int \dfrac{1}{f(x)}dx$$

Comment: should be $1/f(x)=u'(x)/u(x)$

Comment: @omer Thanks for reminding me!